# Unable to receive entire text using winsock in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am making a server client program. I am sending a text of 48KB from to client using winsock, but on client side I receive only 8 KB of text.

Comment: That is normal and expected.  TCP requires a protocol so the receiver can know how much data to expect, the receiver needs to keep calling Receive() until it got everything.  First sending the text length is a basic way, also the way that HTTP works.

Comment: My winsock is in TCP socket mode.So what additional protocol are you referring to ?

Answer (score 0):

TCP can split messages so that data sent as one packet can be received as multiple packages (and vice versa).

The first call to `receive` will gain you 8KB of data, next calls will contain the next 8KB, until all is received.